# Rechart not showing complete line till end of X Axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, charts, recharts

[image]

//As you can see this graph shows  line till only 22nd Feb and not completed
//My problem is that it should show complete line

```
                <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
                    <LineChart
                        margin={{
                            bottom: 40,
                        }}
                    >
                        <XAxis dataKey="key" dy={10} interval={4}>
                            <Label value="Days of Month" offset={-20} position="insideBottom" />
                        </XAxis>

                        <YAxis
                            type="number"
                            domain={[0, 2]}
                            dx={-10}
                            label={{ value: "Revenue", angle: -90, position: "insideLeft", offset: -15 }}
                        />

                        <Tooltip />
                        <Legend verticalAlign="top" align="right" height={36} iconType="circle" />
                        <Line
                            type="linear"
                            data={currentMonthStats}
                            dataKey="Current Month"
                            stroke="#00aab3"
                            label="Current Month"
                            dot={false}
                        />
                        <Line
                            type="linear"
                            data={lastMonthStats}
                            dataKey="Last Month"
                            stroke="#00aab380"
                            dot={false}
                        />
                    </LineChart>
                </ResponsiveContainer>
```

// I tried above solution but it still shows incomplete line

Comment: Do you have data till 25th feb? Also i think data prop should be present on parent LineChart div

Comment: I have data till 28th feb